# NSRegularExpression conditionals to find terminated and non-terminated strings

Tags: objective-c, regex, string, pattern-matching, nsregularexpression

Does `NSRegularExpression` support conditional inside the pattern? I seem to not get the desired effect when I use the following expression to match strings within quotes and strings that are missing an end quote. I get the feeling my expression is just not written correctly:

Regular Expression:

`\".*(?(?=\")(\")|(.))`

Test Strings:

`var name = "A string"; // commment`

`var name = "A string; // comment`

Expected matches (respectively):

`"A string"`

`"A string; // comment`

Comment: did you wanna regex to match both strings?

Comment: no just one. if not the first, then the last

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a lookbehind to make `\"` not to match the `"` followed by semicolon.

```
(?<= )\"[^"]*"?
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jM2lE0/1)

Comment: the above regex would match the both.